# Employment Visa

Tags: contracts, employer, visa

So I have an offer and was handed a contract to me which will be from this August 7th to next year August 6th. I am a foreigner working in this country (Not specified but its in Asia somewhere). Today I just got my working VISA (1 - year only), and the problem is today is 26th of July, but my work starts from August this year to August next year as by the contract, and I am only allowed to work in this country til next year 26th of July ( its a 1 year work VISA).

So my question is what happens to my contract now, since I will only be able to legally work till 26th of July 2019, not the specified 6th of August 2019 as on the contract?

I am genuinely concerned at the moment as it is my first job and I do not want any complications. I would appreciate some serious feedback from perhaps those employers who might have had this kind of experience with their employees in the past. Thank you!

(**NOTE**: I was not aware of the fact that the my legal employment status changes on the day I receive the employment VISA).

**EDIT:** Is it a good idea to just not mention it to my employers and maybe sometime next year June, I can just get the extension of my VISA in the advent my company wants to still keep me?

Comment: It's meaningless to speculate if you wont specify the country, but even if you did this is likely too specific of a legal question to be on-topic here. Ask your prospective employer or contact a legal professional. Perhaps ask for input in the chatroom at [expats.se].

Comment: Do you think it would be a deal-breaker for your employer if you were to shorten your year-long contract by 2 weeks (due to no fault of your own)? Do you think they'd prefer you hiding this from them, or being upfront about it?

Comment: I actually told them about it, and a new contract was written and now it is all taken care of. Thanks for the opinions though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with I would ask the company that you are working for and see what they are willing to do to your contract before you decide you want to move there, because it could all be avoided if they just contract you for less time.
Tell them that your visa only lasts till the 26th of July etc..

If this isn't an option then there is an option to extend your visa if you just search for it online and find the specified country. As long as your work permit is valid you can have this adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

You need both visa and valid contract to work and hence your last day of work will be determined which ever expires earlier (in this case your visa).

I think it is NOT a good idea to not tell your employer about your visa situation. Since it is barely a month apart, they can simply reduce your contract period to match with visa date and that will work well for everyone.  Depending on what extension you get later, you can simply ask for renewal of contract.

Not disclosing your visa status can simply fire back on you as not being honest or transparent about work permit.

Answer (score -1):

Make it a "small issue".

Next time they ask you "did you get that visa?"  Just reply "No problem, I have it, it expires exactly July 26" and leave it at that.

Do not say anything more than that.

Really it is a non-issue.  No problem.

(It is extremely likely they will extend your stay and get you a new visa anyway.  not a big deal.)

It's completely normal that your visa dates do not coincide exactly with other dates.  It is a non-issue - do NOT make an issue about it.

Actually above I recommend ..

> "No problem, I have it, it expires exactly July 26"

- and leave it at that.

An even better idea is just:

> "No problem, I have it, here it is"

and just attach an image of it.  Say **nothing.  They deal with this all the time - it is a non-issue**.

Enjoy your stay!